# Screenshot shows black area with dual monitors on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04

When using the built-in window screenshot function on Ubuntu (`alt-printscreen`) with dual monitors, a black rectangle covers about the top third of the captured window (or that area is not captured). When capturing the entire screen (`printscreen`), the left monitor shows the same size rectangle, but it doesn't cover the window, but pushes it down. It's as if the capture is using the smaller monitor's dimensions, and is not aware of the larger monitor.

Here are the images:

Window capture: http://moby.to/8d69hp
Screen capture: http://moby.to/v99gqs

When using the command line, I get this error:

```
$ gnome-screenshot --window
(gnome-screenshot:8522): GdkPixbuf-CRITICAL **: gdk_pixbuf_composite: assertion `dest_y >= 0 && dest_y + dest_height <= dest->height' failed
```

**System info:**
Ubuntu 10.04.2 LTS (Lucid)
Linux 2.6.32-32-generic
Left monitor (laptop) 1280x800
Right monitor (external) 1920x1080

Video card:

```
$ lspci | grep -i graphics
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.1 Display controller: Intel Corporation Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0c)
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

**Edit:** this does not happen with one monitor or when the monitors are mirrored.
**2nd edit:** if this would be better asked on SuperUser, please let me know.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about system administration, but it would be suitable for [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 1):

That happens because you have different size of monitors, depending on your video card you can play with the sizes and configurations.  Usually the closed drivers of Nvidia or Ati handle this things better.
What type of video card you have

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't really answer the question (I'd still like to know what causes the issue), but others reading this may be interested.

I installed [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org) (`$ sudo apt-get install shutter`) and it works like a charm. Much more feature-rich as well.